# POST request not sending session cookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using the following code to interact with a website:

```
session = requests.session()
get = session.get(LANDING_URL, headers=HEADERS)
post = session.post(LANDING_URL, headers=HEADERS, data=PARAMS)
```

I'm using the `session` object to preserve cookies between call, but the post request following the get request doesn't seem to use the session cookie. The below output is from `pdb`:

```
(Pdb) get.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='ASP.NET_SessionId', value=...)]>
(Pdb) post.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
(Pdb) session.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[Cookie(version=0, name='ASP.NET_SessionId', value=...)]>
```

Does this mean that the post request isn't using the session cookie? If so, why not?

Comment: Could you please run `print(session.cookies.get_dict())` and share the output?

Comment: page may use JavaScript to add cookies and `requests` can't run JavaScript

Comment: you display only cookies send from server, not send to server. `session` should keep all cookies and send them in POST request.

Comment: @furas That makes sense! Is there way to see the body of the post request that I'm sending?

Comment: you can use http://httpbin.org - if you send GET request to http://httpbin.org/get or POST to http://httpbin.org/post then it sends you back (as JSON) all your headers, data, cookies, etc. You can also install local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Man-In-The-Middle-Py](https://mitmproxy.org/) and send request through proxy. You will see body and headers in proxy.

Comment: you can also check `post.request.body`, `post.request.headers`. I never used it  but it should have body and headers sent to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page may use JavaScript to add cookies and requests can't run JavaScript.

Using `get.cookies`, `post.cookies` you display only cookies send from server, not send to server.

`session` should keep all cookies from previous requests and send them in POST request.

You can use [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/). If you send GET request to [httpbin.org/get](http://httpbin.org/get) or POST to [httpbin.org/post](http://httpbin.org/post) then it sends you back (as JSON) all your headers, data, cookies, etc. There are other useful functions on [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/)

You can also install local proxy server like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [Man-In-The-Middle-Py](https://mitmproxy.org/) and send request through proxy. You will see body and headers in proxy. You can use proxy with web browser and with your script to compare your requests with request from browser.

You can also check `post.request.body`, `post.request.headers`. I never used it but it should have body and headers sent to server.